# It is possible to get tier demoted on season 5?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is it possible to fall from Platinum to Gold and from Gold to Silver on season 5?
Since in every season stuff like that change I would like to know. And if yes, how many games you need to lose in a row in order to get demoted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is still possible to get demoted **if your MMR is at least 1 tier below your current tier**. However you wil recieve a warning first about a possible demotion.

Other than that it's obviously also possible to get demoted by the LP decay that's triggered from inactivity.

Comment: you can not fall from gold to silver due to lp decay as that was removed. I think the same may go for plat to gold but i am not very sure about that